# Can't call c-functions from NASM in VC++ except main, getting linking error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker, nasm

Can anyone please tell me why I can't call any global functions from NASM, **except** main ? (Before you ask) Yes, I have read all the questions regarding this in stackoverflow and in internet for about 8 hours.

**C++ code.**

```
void main();

extern "C" void nasm_function(void);

void c_function()
{
}

void main()
{
    nasm_function();

    system("pause");
}
```

**NASM code,**

```
extern _c_function
extern _main

segment .text

global _nasm_function
_nasm_function:
call _main  
call _c_function
```

**Output,**

> 1>Linking... 1>my_asm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _c_function 1>F:\Projects\OSDev\assmebly_test\Debug\project.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

as you can see, we don't get linking error for main. I don't know why. :)

**Settings,**

```
building nasm using custom-build-rules with nasm.exe -f win32 
Calling convention is __cdecl (/Gd)
Visual Studio 2008
NASM version 2.05
Didn't include my_asm.obj as a input to linker
```

Anyone please tell me what is the issue ? Thanks in advance. (note that this is a sample program, but still getting the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is *name mangling*. The solution is `extern "C"`.

Comment: Should  "extern "C" void c_function(void);" this work ? Nope :(

Comment: err... I was such an idiot. Yes, it is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: if anyone is still getting the error, what went wrong for me is, I was trying to extern the function with different set of arguments than the original c-function